# curses.wrapper() isn't working [python]

Tags: python, terminal, curses

I am trying to sort out things quickly with curses.wrapper() function. As the docs say, it accepts a `function` or `object` whose first argument will be the screen which then used to further work on the screen. This is the code:

```
def function(screen):
    screen.addstr(0, 0, "print something here")
    screen.refresh()

curses.wrapper(function)
```

But, nothing prints back on the screen. Control just goes in and out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is (or at least could be…) working just fine; it just finishes so fast you never get a chance to see it.

You put a string on the screen with `addstr` and `refresh`. Then you immediately return from `function`, which returns from `wrapper`, which restores the terminal to its pre-`curses` state, so the results vanish.

If you want to see something happen, you'll need to put in some kind of delay. For example:

```
def function(screen):
    screen.addstr(0, 0, "print something here")
    screen.refresh()
    screen.getkey()
```

Now it'll display "print something here" in the top left, then wait for you to press a key, during which time you can see that string.